# What kind of analytical function could resemble that plot?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I am in the middle of making a model, and I am looking for an analytical expression which could resemble this evolution for one of the parameters:

[image]

In short: a sudden increase from 0 to a global maximum, followed by slower decrease. Once I have an idea of a functional form that presents the right characteristics, I can tweak it (peak height, peak position) to my liking.

The only expression I've been able to come up with so far involves rather high powers (12 and 6) of $1/x$:

[image]

(In case you wonder how I came to think of this one, it's the Boltzmann factor of a [Lennard-Jones potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential)…)

Comment: Maybe the [Laplace transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) of your data could show some structure inside of this impulse...

Comment: @LeonidKovalev well, actually, I am not exactly “fitting experimental data”, but generalizing the expected evolution of one model parameter. I know it starts at zero, jumps and goes down… I've edited the question to reflect that better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So is this supposed to be for $r > 0$?  You might try more generally $y = k e^{a/r^b - c/r^d}$, where $b < d$.  The maximum is at $r = \left( \frac{cd}{ab}\right)^{1/(d-b)}$, and
the limit as $r \to \infty$ is $k$.